# How to solve Generic error in GDI+ and Out of memory

Tags: c#, memory, gdi

In C# I Start a thread that find,crop and saves some cells in a picture. But while running throws an exception :

[image: C# Out of memory]

This is my code :

```
Global.ThreadManager.StartThread(a =>
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap croppedBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.Path + "image.jpg");
                    croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(
                    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                        Convert.ToInt32(xCenter - width),
                        Convert.ToInt32(yCenter - width),
                        width * 2,
                        width * 2),
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare
                    );
                    if (!File.Exists(Path + "MorphologySperms"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path + "MorphologySperms");
                    }
                    croppedBitmap.Save(Path + "Sperms\\" + "sperm_" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                };
            });
```

Comment: looks like you keep creating bitmaps but never destroying them.  so yeah, you run out of gdi heap space.  try cleaning up after yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need** to dispose your images, you cant rely on the garbage collector to find these in-time and release the unmanaged *GDI* resources, this is a one way street to an exception

Also

- [`ConvertTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2) seems like a waste, just cast if you need to
- If you need to combine paths, use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_)
- Use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) instead of plus'ing strings together
- If you need to escape a character like a backslash, use [Verbatim String Literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) @"..."

**Fixed**

```
using (var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.Path + "image.jpg"))
{
   using (var croppedBitmap = image.Clone(new Rectangle((int)xCenter - width, (int)yCenter - width, width * 2, width * 2), PixelFormat.DontCare))
   {
      // not sure what you are doing here, though it doesnt make sense
      if (!File.Exists(Path + "MorphologySperms"))
      {
         // why are you creating a directory and not using it
         Directory.CreateDirectory(Path + "MorphologySperms");
      }

      // use Path.Combine
      var somePath = Path.Combine(path, "Sperms");
      croppedBitmap.Save( Path.Combine(somePath, $"sperm_{I}.jpg"));
   }
}
```

Also its extremely debatable and suspect to use `clone` like this